# Cauchy Integral Formula over Annulus.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

I was trying to follow a proof of Laurent's Expansion Theorem from here: [Proof of Laurent series co-efficients in Complex Residue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126321/proof-of-laurent-series-co-efficients-in-complex-residue)

However, I did not understand the following step:

> Let () be analytic in a region bounded by two concentric circles
>   1 and 2 where the radius of 1 is greater than the radius of 2.
>   By Cauchy's integral formula, we are able to show that:
>
> $$
> f(z_0) = \frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_1}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz-\frac{1}{2i\pi}\oint_{C_2}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz
> $$

How is this evident from Cauchy's integral theorem, I don't see it as obvious.
Is it necessary to add two lines from the inter circle to the outer to "split" the annulus into different regions?

Comment: This requires the 'homotopic version' of Cauchy's Theorem, not the basic version. The two circles together with two line segments give a path that is homotopic to a constant and hence the integral over the contour is $0$.